# Application branding

Tags: android, android-theme

I would like my application to be available under different brandings - this means that it must be possible to easily change background bitmaps in few places, but also change text resources.

My plan is to use themes and styles, I know they can be used for switching bitmaps but will they allow me to change also texts in TextViews for example?

Is it also possible to specify in style or theme a text identifier and later dynamically read it in code?

[EDIT]

After some investigation, of course texts can be substituted with styles. Another problem that comes with application branding is the need to change package name - otherwise Google Play wont accept our branded application.

[EDIT]

After more investigation, below I include small sample on how to add two switchable themes that will allow to substitude drawable in activity layout, and text resource in textview. Whats left is to call setTheme(R.style.Theme1);    or setTheme(R.style.Theme2); in onCreate before setContentView.

```
<-- attrs.xml />
<resources>
    <attr name="ProductName" format="reference"/>    
    <attr name="ProductBackground" format="integer"/>
</resources>

<-- styles.xml />
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme1" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="ProductName">@string/s_product_1_name</item>
        <item name="ProductBackground">@drawable/back_1_vga</item>
    </style>    
    <style name="Theme2" parent="android:Theme.Light" >         
        <item name="ProductName">@string/s_product_2_name</item>
        <item name="ProductBackground">@drawable/back_2_vga</item>
    </style>
</resources>

<-- my activity layout />
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="?ProductBackground"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:text="?ProductName" 
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have a stupid answer, probably. I'd put my string in... strings.xml, name it "brand" and my picture in... the drawable folder(s), named "logo.png" - Then change the string and the picture for each customer who wants a brandized version of my app.

Comment: @Vyger the problem is also to change package name, and automate all of it. I have added answer basing on what I have learned over time since asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two aproaches to make different brandings of you app:

1) Split your app into multiple library projects, common code is in lets say common_lib library project, and all your brandings are in separate projects using common_lib but changing some of the resources, like strings, some drawables, also package name. This is the aproach we have choosen in our app.

2) Use gradle product flavors: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html, I think this should now be the prefered solution.